# Categories or Structures: Most efficient way to organize FAQ sections

Tags: entries, categories, relations, structure, category

Working on a plan for a site that has multiple audiences, with a FAQ section for each audience.

- FAQ entries are organized by Topic (**Finance**, **Advertising**, **Publicity**)

  - each FAQ entry can be associated with multiple topics
- FAQS and Topics are also organized by audience: (**trainee**, **associate**, **lead**)

  - a given FAQ entry or an entire Topic full of entries can be associated with multiple Audiences

It would be nice to be able to order the entries in each topic, but not a must have.

The three separate FAQ pages would have content that maps out like this, as an example:

### ***Trainee Audience page***

```
Advertising
     Ad Entry 1
     Ad Entry 2
Finance
     Fin Entry 1
Publicity
     Pub Entry 1
```

### ***Associate Audience page***

```
Advertising
     Ad Entry 2
     Ad Entry 3
Publicity
     Pub Entry 2
```

### ***Lead Audience page***

```
Advertising
     Ad Entry 1
     Ad Entry 2
     Ad Entry 3
Finance
     Fin Entry 1
     Fin Entry 2
     Fin Entry 3
```

I know that this can be accomplished in various ways using categories, structures, and related entries, but I'm aiming for efficiency, then ease of editing for the users.

I've tentatively landed on this: 
One main **Structure**, with **Topic** and **FAQ** entry types. Both entry types have a **Category** field to select audience

but not sure if I'm missing a better option for performance/ease of use.  Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track. In cases like these, I've found it helpful to enter a small bit of representative content, and then show it to someone else. That will help you uncover any unexpected use cases / data relationships that you hadn't considered.

Answer (score 2):

If your clients wants to have control about the order of the entries for each audience,  e.g.

```
 Trainee
 Advertising
    Ad Entry 2
    Ad Entry 3

 Associate
 Advertising
    Ad Entry 3
    Ad Entry 1
    Ad Entry 2
```

a good solution might be a entries field. The ability to simply drag and drop entries to change the order is the most intuitive option from my experience. If you have many entries you could combine both logics - e.g. render first all elements that you selected with the entries field and after that add the missing ones according to your categories / structure.

Comment: You are right, reordering entries this way seems like it would be easiest for users.  

In this scenario, it seems like I would create a separate **Channel** to store the FAQs.  Then, they would be ordered in a **Structure** with an **entries** field.  

Would it make sense to do that in 1 structure, with 1st-level branches for Audience?

`Resources (Structure)
     Trainee (audience entry type)
          Advertising (topic entry type, with "Entries" field to relate and order FAQs)
          Finance
     Associate (audience entry type)
          Advertising
          Publicity
`